# Removing loaded jQuery AJAX element

Tags: jquery, ajax, dialog

I was working on a dialog with content loaded by AJAX, but I'm not able to remove it.
A must was to have a multiple, php-supported, drag-able and close-able dialog.
*(.center() function present)*

```
$('a.event').click(function() {
    var url = this.href;
    var getrel = $(this).attr('rel');
    var getid = $(this).attr('id');
    var dialog = $('<div id="event_'+getid+'" class="izModal '+getrel+'"></div>').appendTo('body');
    dialog.load( url, {}, function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) { $('#event_'+getid+'').append("<a class='close' rel='"+getid+"'>x</a>"); } ).center().draggable();
    return false;
});
```

And to close it:

```
        $('a.close').click(function(event){
            var getevent = $(this).attr('rel');
            $('#event_'+getevent+'').hide();
        });
```

I've tried (as you may see) to give every dialog an id to close it.
Also tried with **this.parent** , **hide()** , change the CSS and **remove()**.

Can somebody spot the error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you also add in a chunk of actual inserted HTML from the app? Try using FireBug if you're using Firefox and not already using that add-on, otherwise you should be able to right click and choose "Inspect Element" to get the inserted HTML. `can you insert TWO of those blocks for us? actual live blocks`

Comment: Nick Craver gave the correct answer! I already use those kind of plugins (in Chrome) and everything was right, but now it's fixed! Just have to wait till I can accept the answer. Thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating the links dynamically do you need something like a [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) approach, like this:

```
$('a.close').live('click', function(event){
  var getevent = $(this).attr('rel');
  $('#event_'+getevent+'').hide();
});
```

When using `$('a.close').click()` you're finding the elements that exist *when it's run*, new elements that are created later won't have a `click` handler, [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)  resolves this by relying on event bubbling...so it works on elements created later.

Comment: Good call Nick, I hadn't noticed that tidbit